# Using ProGuard, keep class fields with wildcard

Tags: java, maven, proguard

I'd like to keep certain class fields untouched by ProGuard if the field name starts with a certain string. Currently I'm just setting all fields to be kept, but would like to refine that to keep **all** public & protected fields, and only the private fields that start with this string.

This is the current config in my pom.xml:

```
<option>-keepclassmembers class com.my.package.** { &lt;fields&gt;; }</option>
```

I have tried the following, and similar variants:

```
<option>-keepclassmembers class com.my.package.** { public *; protected *; private string***; }</option>
```

But ProGuard throws an error (works fine when I just use "private *;"):

```
[proguard] Error: Expecting class member name before ';' in argument number 39
```

I'm guessing I'm either using the wildcard incorrectly, or this can't be done? I have check the usage/examples section of the ProGuard site and other examples through Google, and I see usually the full definition of the field might be needed (*private final String stringVariable*), but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern is intended to look like Java, but with wildcards. You can use the following:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.my.package.** {
    public protected <fields>;
    private *** string*;
}
```

The wildcard `<fields>` matches all fields (any type, any name), in this case constrained to only match public or protected fields.

On the next line, the wildcard `***` matches any type (including primitive types and array types) and the expression `string*` matches any name starting with 'string', in this case further constrained to private fields.

If useful, you could add other constraints to both lines, for example `!static` to only match non-static fields.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I'm looking for. Will test it in the next day or so and get back with results. :)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Cheers. :)

Comment: Is there any doc for wildcards?